# How to protect a range of cells depending on a value of specified cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

How to protect or lock a range of cells depending on a value of specified cell?
for example when A1="s"; the range A2:A11 will be locked and I can't modify any cell.

Comment: Excel isn't a tool designed for this purpose. You need to use macros for that.

Comment: Have you researched or attempted anything yet? Share with us where you are at in the process.

Comment: Not yet, my problem is I don't want to use macros.